# Return new array containing strings which contain specific words

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am trying to take an array and return a new array containing only those whose surname is 'Smith'.

I am attempting to .filter this and have been trying for quite a while but am completely out of ideas.

Please take a look at my code below, I know I am miles off, and let me kno where I might get better results? Thanks guys!

```
const smiths = arr.filter(function(smith) {
  let nameSplit = smith.split(' ')
  return nameSplit === "Smith" 
 });                               
return smiths;
```

Example:

```
arr = ['Penelope Smith', 'Charlotte Smither'] returns ['Penelope Smith']
```

Comment: I don't think you're understanding the [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@slouisa you almost had it, you were just missing the index for the split array.

```
const lastNameToFilter = "smith";
const smiths = arr.
```

```js
arr = ['Penelope Smith', 'Charlotte Smither'];

const lastNameToFilter = "Smith".toLowerCase();

const smiths = arr.filter(function(fullname) {
    let nameSplit = fullname.split(' ');
    let lastNameIndex = 1;

    return nameSplit[lastNameIndex].toLowerCase() === lastNameToFilter;
});                

console.log(smiths);
```

```
filter(function(smith) {
    let nameSplit = smith.split(' ');
    let lastNameIndex= 1;
    return nameSplit[lastNameIndex].toLowerCase() === lastNameToFilter;
});                               
return smiths;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this using [`localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) to take care of case sensitivity etc:

```js
var arr = ['Penelope Smith', 'Charlotte Smither', 'John smith']

const smiths = (a, s) => a.filter(x => x.split(' ')[1]
   .localeCompare(s, 'en', {sensitivity: 'base'})==0)

console.log(smiths(arr, 'Smith'))
```

Another approach you could take is via [`endsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) and [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase):

```js
var arr = ['Penelope Smith', 'Charlotte Smither', 'John smith', 'Mark DeSmith']

const smiths = (a,s) => a.filter(x => 
   x.toLowerCase().endsWith(` ${s.toLowerCase()}`))

console.log(smiths(arr, 'Smith'))
```

> Note that `endsWith` does not have support in IE